# Black Color is completely transparent | Windows 11 Transparent Application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, winapi, windows-11

I am creating a transparent messaging Application which should be overlayed over the Desktop. I'm currently using Unity for the development (but this should be irrelevant because I think its a problem with Windows 11). I upgraded lately to Windows 11 and since then (I think) these problems occur.

In Unity I have a script which turns my Application to a fullscreen transparent Window. But for some reason the "whiteness" of any color displayed also defines its transparency on the final build, with black ==> full transparent and white ==> full opaque.

I tested this with multiple different Projects from different sources all with the same result.

I am not too experienced with the WindowsAPI and I don't know if this is a new restriction of Windows 11 or if I am missing something here...

I would appreciate if someone wants to share some thoughts with me.

Here is the relevant Code which is used to create the transparent windows and 2 Screenshots displaying the issue.

```
private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private const long WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000L;
private const long WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020L;
private const uint LWA_COLORKEY = 0x00000001;
private const uint LWA_ALPHA = 0x00000002;
private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);

public void Start()
{
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            m_HWnd = GetActiveWindow();
            var margins = new MARGINS() {cxLeftWidth = -1};
            DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_HWnd, ref margins);
            
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_HWnd, 0, 0, LWA_ALPHA);
            
            SetWindowPos(m_HWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
#endif
            Application.runInBackground = true;
}

public void Update()
{
     m_ClickThroughProvider.Update(this.gameObject);
            
     SetClickThrough(m_ClickThroughProvider.GetClickThrough());
}

private void SetClickThrough(bool shouldClickThrough)
{
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
     if (shouldClickThrough)
         SetWindowLongPtrA(m_HWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
     else
         SetWindowLongPtrA(m_HWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED);

#endif
}
```

Here the first Screenshot how it **should** look like (in the Unity Editor):

[image: How it should look like]

Here the second Screenshot how the build application looks like (no changes in the UI only the code listed above runs in the build (and not in the Unity Editor)):

[image]

Comment: *"for some reason the "whiteness" of any color displayed also defines its transparency on the final build, with black ==> full transparent and white ==> full opaque."* - That's just a mathematical property inherent to [premultiplied alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Straight_versus_premultiplied) transparency (which is what Windows uses). Assuming that you want the alpha channel to be independent of the color you're going to have to build the alpha channel manually. It's not obvious to me what your predicate is for choosing between transparent and opaque.

Comment: I don't see any C++ code, kindly remove the tag if not needed.